# Drop values based on another variable

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create a linear regression model between age and salary for example. I am particularly interested in the younger population so I decided to create another variable

```
age.young <- age[!age >= 40]
```

So now my age.young variable is from 3-39 years old. Now because I want to run the relationship between salary and age.young, I need to create another variable salary.young that correspond to the people between 3-39 years old.

How do I do this? 
Is this:

```
salary.young <- salary[!age >= 40]
```

Comment: Put your variables in a data.frame and subset the whole data.frame.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way I can change 50 of the variables simultaneous? Meaning I want to drop the values that correspond with age greater than 39 in other 50 variables.

Comment: Yes, use a data.frame.

Comment: Hi. Can you be more specific about it. I dont know how to use a data.frame to remove all of these. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please read an introduction to R. It doesn't get more basic than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with dataframes instead of variables. This should work (using `mydata1` as the name of your dataset):

`salary.young<-mydata1[["salary"]][mydata1$age<40]`

Or like the comment:

`mydata1.young`<-subset(mydata1,mydata1$age<40)`

Comment: Probably because you are not using a dataset but separate atomic vectors. Show us a sample of the data you are using with `head(mydata1)`.

Comment: Hi. I was able to use it. This is what I have: 

ex1.young <-subset(ex1,ex1$age<40).

So now if I want to have the salary with the corresponding age of lower than 40, it will be ex1.young$salary?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can integrate it into one line:
`mydata1.young.salary<-subset(mydata1,mydata1$age<40)$salary`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one last questions. So in the new dataset, ex1.young, I need to change all the variables to dummy variables (it will be 1 if the value is greater than 8 and be 9 if the value if less than 8) and I do not want to do it manually. Here is what I have so far: 

dummy24 <- as.numeric(education>= 8). Is there a way I can do this in one go?

Comment: `mydata.young[mydata.young>=8]<-1`
`mydata.young[mydata.young<8]<-9`

Comment: thank you. SHould I put a ] after -1 and -9? 
Because I have:
ex1.young[ex1.young>=8]<-1 and R said : In Ops.factor(left, right) : >= not meaningful for factors

Comment: HI, I really hope you can take a look at what I have so far. So when I had: ex1.young[ex1.young>=8]<-1, R said " >= not meaningful for factors " so I used: ex1.youngb<- lapply(ex1.young, as.numeric) to make the whole dataset numeric. But I was still not able to run  ex1.young[ex1.young>=8]<-1 because R said: "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'". what does this mean?

Comment: Oh. I think because I have to make it as.matrix and not as.numeric? I tried and it worked but not sure whether this is giving me what I wanted